# C# check which integer is higher

Tags: c#, compare, integer

I have two integers, `int1` and `int2`. I want to check which one is the higher one. How can I do this the best? Is there an C#.NET function for this or do I have to write it myself?

Ofcource I can do something similar to this:

```
if (int1 < int2)
    return int1;
else
    return int2;
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way for doing this?

yours,
Bernhard

Comment: Don't you think the simple method you described is going to be most elegant way? You wanted more complicated way it seems :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`Math.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx)

Usage:

```
int highest = Math.Max(int1, int2);
```

It's overloaded for all numeric types.

Answer (score 3):

use this :

```
   int result = Math.Max(int1,int2);
```

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator is a bit nicer:

```
return (int1 > int2) ? (int1) : (int2) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = int1 > int2 ? int1 : int2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a more elegant way of doing this going forward you could use method extensions.  See Example below

```
public static int CompareTo(this int src, int compare)
{
     return src == compare ? 0 : (Math.Max(src, compare) == src ? 1 : -1);
}
```

HTH,

Matti